# A power series that converges for $|x| \leq 1$ and diverges otherwise.

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find a power series $\sum a_n z^n$ that converges for $|x| \leq  1$ and diverges otherwise.

I think I have one I just want to be sure.

So, the series:

$\sum \frac{z^n}{n^2}$

has radius of convergence of 1.  So it converges when $|z| <1$ and diverges when $|z| >1$, correct?

And we know it converges at $z= \pm 1$ by the comparison test, correct?  This part is where I'm having trouble with.  Could someone explain in detail how to use the comparison test with this? I know the comparison test says, "if you have two series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ with $a_n, b_n \geq0$ and $a_n \leq b_n$, then if $\sum b_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ converges." But what other series would you use in the comparison test.  I also know that $|\frac{z^n}{n^2}|= \frac{1}{n^2}$.  Can you use this fact?

Please help! This series would work correct?

Comment: You don't want the comparison test, you want the integral test or the p-test.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the comparison test. If $|z|=1$ then $\sum z^2/n^2$ converges *absolutely* so it converges.

Comment: Brillant! So, since $\sum |\frac{z^n}{n^2}| = \sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ and we know the latter converges, then  $\sum \frac{z^n}{n^2}$ converges as well?

Comment: @user201483 Yes.

Comment: And that goes for any series? If the absolute value of the series converges, then the original series converges?

Comment: @user201483 Yes.

Comment: Nice. Also, I love your hat choice!